# Bash command to see if a specific line of a file is empty

Tags: bash

I'm trying to fix a bash script by adding in some error catching. I have a file (list.txt) that normally has content like this:

```
People found by location:  
person: john [texas]  
more info on john
```

Sometimes that file gets corrupted, and it only has that first line:

```
People found by location:
```

I'm trying to find a method to check that file to see if any data exists on line 2, and I want to include it in my bash script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and clean:

```
if test $(sed -n 2p < /path/to/file); then
    # line 2 exists and it is not blank
else
    # otherwise...
fi
```

With `sed` we extract the second line only. The `test` expression will evaluate to true only if there is a second non-blank line in the file.

Comment: `wc -l /path` will print two columns, only one of which is an integer.

Comment: It is arguably cleaner to do: `wc -l < /path`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'm not quite able to get this one to work still... it returned "line 1: test: too many arguments".. I'm trying William's recommendation now. Thank you all!

Comment: Adding the < between -1 and /path as William suggested fixed the issue for me. I can't say thank you enough. Cheers!

Comment: @Janos Did I say anything?  In fact, your edits reveal the various *ideas* you had :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to check whether line 2 of a given file contains any data or not.

```
[ "$(sed -n '2p' inputfile)" != "" ] && echo "Something present on line 2" || echo "Line 2 blank"
```

This would work even if the inputfile has just one line.

If you simply want to check whether the inputfile has one line or more, you can say:

```
[ "$(sed -n '$=' z)" == "1" ] && echo "Only one line" || echo "More than one line"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to check if your file has more than 1 line

```
if (( $(wc -l < filename) > 1 )); then
    echo I have a 2nd line
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which doesn't require external commands is:

```
if ( IFS=; read && read -r && [[ -n $REPLY ]]; ) < /path/to/file; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```